# Best approach handling Relational ActiveRecords in Yii

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, yii

I'm quite confused with the different ways of "acquiring" data from my database using ActiveRecords. For this specific problem I don't know wether I should use model->findAll(), criteria (which would allow using pagination), or plain SQL if necessary (given that I need to display the output in a GridView).

What I'm trying to do here is list all the companies in my table 'company' and how much money has each of them payed. Payments are registered in the table 'transaction', which has the field 'value' representing the amount of money.

So, if I had to use a SQL query, it would be something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM company 
LEFT OUTER JOIN transaction 
    ON company.id = transaction.company 
GROUP BY value
```

In short, what is the easiest way to achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: it is always advisable to use activerecord methods for querying data

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question, I forgot to say I didn't manage to achieve this with any method, so some explication on how to use the ActiveRecord for this specific problem would be really useful

Comment: have u defined relation between the two models?

Comment: Yes, for company:
'transaction' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Transaction', 'company'),

and for transaction:
'company' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Company', 'id'),

Comment: Could you explain, what solutions you have tried? Your problem is almost the most simple relational query one can think of. What part of the [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) was unclear for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code for dataprovider

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Company', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'with'=>array('transaction'),
        'group' = 't.value'
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>20,
    ),
));
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. You don't need to add any extra condition if you already defined your [relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail). A simple `'with'=>'transaction'` is all you need.

Comment: For some reason it wont work now... Its not making the JOIN for some reason: SQL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.value' in 'group statement'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`description` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`sector` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`num_employees` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`countries` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`nif` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`code_agent` AS `t0_c6` FROM `company` `t` GROUP BY t.value LIMIT 20